# Sharing and saving pictures from app

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I'm still working on my image gallery app. My new problem is the FileProvider. I have pictures in a subdirectory of the asset folder and I want to save a picture on the device - and sharing it to another app - when the relative button is clicked. In the developer guide, I found the use of the FileProvider which still doesn't work for me. The method **getFilesDir()** gives the error "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". I don't know how to solve this and not even if this is really what I need to do. If anyone has another idea to save/share my picture I would be grateful :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfRJa.jpg)

(I followed exactly every step from the guide until this)

Comment: 'I want to save a picture to the gallery -' ? Unclear what you want. The 'gallery' is no storage place. And the Gallery app just shows all the image files which are on your device. Please rephrase.

Comment: sorry to the user's device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MediaStore to access gallery images.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html

Answer (score 1):

getFilesDir() should be called with a reference to a context. You are using 'Context' class name simply.

Suppose if your Activity name is 'SampleActivity',  try

```
SampleActivity.this.getFilesDir()
```

Comment: thanks, solved it :) so the FileProvider is the right way to share and save pictures? I'm newbie and still have to experiment all these things

Comment: `so the FileProvider is the right way to share and save pictures?`. Share and save are two questions. For the first i would say: FileProvider is not able to share pictures from assets. For the second one, for saving pictures -from where?- to file system you do not need a file provider. You can just save them.

Comment: FileProvider is used basically for sharing file with other apps in a secure way. It does not have to do anything with saving them. For more detailed information please see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/6266/fileprovider#t=20170209193845899456)

Comment: thanks to both (and by the way, I have to save pictures from my app to the device gallery, and sharing pictures to social networks)

Comment: `to the device gallery` ??? Now you are doing it again! How hard can it be?

Comment: I replied to your other comment